# Problem with Keras LSTM input_shape: expected lstm_1_input to have shape (500, 2) but got array with shape (500, 5)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, lstm

`x_train` and `y_train` are input and output of my model with shapes of `(6508, 500, 5), (6508, 5)` respectively.

And the model is like this:

```py
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(units=96, return_sequences=True, input_shape=x_train.shape[1:]))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(LSTM(units=96, return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(LSTM(units=96))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(units=5))

model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam', metrics=['mse'])

model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=epochs, batch_size=batch_size)
```

Model Summary:

```
Model: "sequential_1"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
lstm_1 (LSTM)                (None, 500, 96)           39168     
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_1 (Dropout)          (None, 500, 96)           0         
_________________________________________________________________
lstm_2 (LSTM)                (None, 500, 96)           74112     
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_2 (Dropout)          (None, 500, 96)           0         
_________________________________________________________________
lstm_3 (LSTM)                (None, 96)                74112     
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_3 (Dropout)          (None, 96)                0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 5)                 485       
=================================================================
Total params: 187,877
Trainable params: 187,877
Non-trainable params: 0
```

The problem is `lstm_1` requires input_shape (500, 2) and my data shape is (500, 5):

```
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected lstm_1_input to have shape (500, 2) but got array with shape (500, 5)
```

And I print layers' shape:

```py
for layer in model.layers:
    print(layer.input_shape, end='\t')

# (None, 500, 5)  (None, 500, 96) (None, 500, 96) (None, 500, 96) (None, 500, 96) (None, 96)      (None, 96)
```

It prints `(None, 500, 5)` for `lstm_1` so I can't figure out the problem.

```
Keras==2.3.0
tf==1.14.0
```

**UPDATE:**

Using `keras==2.2.5` or `tf.keras` solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Mentioning the Solution in Answer Section for the Benefit of the Community.

Using `tf.keras` instead of `keras` has resolved the problem.